# Graphing Interaction Terms in Linear Regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I don't understand what the following error means.

**Code:**

```
library(interactions)

df = read.csv(file="birthweight_data.csv", sep=",")[c("fnocig", "fage", "fedyrs")]
df=rename(df, `Cigarettes Smoked Per Day` = `fnocig`)
df=rename(df, `Father's Age` = `fage`)
df=rename(df, `Years of Education` = `fedyrs`)

model = lm(`Cigarettes Smoked Per Day` ~ `Father's Age` + `Years of Education`, data = df)

interact_plot(model, pred=`Father's Age`, modx=`Years of Education`, plot.points=TRUE)
```

**Error:**

[image]

**The Data Frame `print(df)`:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the examples in the documentation for `interact_plot`, you need to fit the interaction term between predictor and moderator in the `lm()` call.

Try:

```
lm(`Cigarettes Smoked Per Day` ~ `Father's Age` * `Years of Education`, data = df)
```